# Trying to remove the last "and" at the end of my output list

Tags: c#, loops, format

For my C# programming homework, we had to write a program that allows the user to input an integer and use a loop to print out the factors of that integer.
I got the program to output the integers.
The problem is, for example, when I enter in the integer "24", I want the output to be 
`1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 6 and 8 and 12 and 24`

but the output that comes out is 
`1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 6 and 8 and 12 and 24 and`

I don't want the extra "and" at the end of my Factors List

Here is what my code looks like:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, b;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your integer: ");
            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
            {
                if (a % b == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(b + " ");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The output **has** to be formatted as 
`1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 6 and 8 and 12 and 24`
or else I won't get credit for the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *enumerate* factors, and then `Join` them with `" and "`

```
 private static IEnumerable<int> Factors(int value) {
   // Simplest, not that efficient
   for (int i = 1; i <= value; ++i)
     if (value % i == 0)
       yield return i;
 } 

 ...

 Console.Write(string.Join(" and ", Factors(24)));
```

Or you can add `" and "` *before*, not *after* printing factors (`i`)

```
 int value = 24;

 bool firstTime = true; 

 // Simplest, not that efficient
 for (int i = 1; i <= value; ++i) {
   if (value % i == 0) {
     // print "and" before printing i
     if (!firstTime)         
       Console.Write(" and ");

     firstTime = false;   

     Console.Write(i);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the second option

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the numbers to a `List` and printing after the loop:

```
int a, b;
a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var result = new List<int>();
for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
{
    if (a % b == 0)
    {
        result.Add(b);
    }
}

Console.Write(string.Join(" and ", result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //get input from user
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your integer: ");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //enumerate factors
        var factors = Enumerable.Range(1, a)
            .Where(i => a % i == 0).ToArray();

        //join for nicely printed output
        Console.Write(string.Join(" and ", factors));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a string and output that string becouse it allows you to do more things with it, then do something like this:

```
        int a, b;
        string x="";
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your integer: ");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
        {
            if (a % b == 0)
            {
                x=x + b.toString() +" and";
            }
        }
```

if you know that always will be an "and" at the end you can simply do this

```
string x = x.Substring(0, x.Length - 3);
```

and then

```
Console.Write(x);
Console.ReadLine();
```